# Flex material cell, Long "Word", wrap

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

I've got the following code:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-syqjgp

I'm having trouble trying to get the text in the data cells to wrap properly.

To see it not working do the following:

1. From the **Select an Existing Element (2)** drop down, select `From Data 01 To Another Data entry`
2. Scroll down to the **Data01 Fields** entry and expand it by clicking on it.
3. Examine the top two rows' data cells for the **Destination Field**.

It has very long data in it, and I would like it to wrap, but it's not.

I've tried, with no success:

```
.input {
    flex-wrap:wrap
}
```

I've tried, with no success:

```
.mat-cell {
    padding: 0 10px;
    flex: 1;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: 48px;
}
```

And I have commented the **height: 48px** out too.

Can the input text be wrapped?

Comment: Why don't you just use textarea instead of input?

Comment: @G.Tranter, I believe it has  to stay a mat-input for the mat-form-field it is.  Do you have a sample of a Angular 6 material form with a text area that has text wrapping?  Thanks.

Comment: You can use textarea just like input - use `<textarea matInput>` in place of `<input matInput>` - and remember that you need to close the textarea tag. Both work with MatFormField. See https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#-code-lt-input-gt-code-and-code-lt-textarea-gt-code-attributes. Text area has an auto resize feature as well which might be useful.

Comment: @G.Tranter Thank You.  I foolishly forgot that `<input>` elements cannot be multi-line.  So `<textarea>` is the way to go.  Now I need to figure out how to autosize it with the data that's in it.  Any help here?  Please don't forget to write up an Answer below so I can check it off. :D

Comment: @G.Tranter nevermind about autoresize.  The link you gave for the input and text area matInputs shows that. :foolish grin: